# Get Outlook Group Calendars using Pywin32 (win32com.client)

Tags: python, outlook, ms-office, pywin32, win32com

I'm trying to figure out how I can access the calendars for different Outlook groups that I am apart of. I'm using win32com and Python 3.9 for this task, and would prefer to avoid going the RESTful/auth token route as that would be a fair bit of overhead for what is supposed to be a simple script inserting a few calendar appointments.

I'm able to get my own appointments using the following code:

```
import win32com.client

application = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
namespace = application.GetNamespace('MAPI')

cal = namespace.GetDefaultFolder(9)
    
for item in cal.Items:
    print(item.Subject)
```

Returning the subject line of every appointment in my personal calendar.

I'm also able to get the same information using GetSharedDefaultFolder:

```
application = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
namespace = application.GetNamespace('MAPI')

recipient = namespace.createRecipient("{my_email}")
resolved = recipient.Resolve()

sharedCalendar = namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recipient, 9)

for item in sharedCalendar.Items:
    print(item.Subject)
```

I read that you want to pass the email/user of the person who created the desired calendar as the recipient, but I have had no luck with this.

In attempting to use the creator's email, I get the following error:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'The operation failed because of a registry or installation problem. Restart Outlook and try again. If the problem persists, reinstall.', None, 0, -2147221219), None)
```

And if I attempt to use their (lastName, firstName), I get the following:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2009857777, 'OLE error 0x8834010f', None, None)
```

Note that I'm referring to **GROUP** calendars, not Shared Calendars. I'm not sure if there's actually a difference between the two, but they appear as different sections on Outlook for me.

Some references I've been referring to (for others who find this page and are having this issue):
[Read Outlook Events via Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477599/read-outlook-events-via-python)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getdefaultfolder (and related pages)
[Problem with read Outlook shared calendar via python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58971911/problem-with-read-outlook-shared-calendar-via-python)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/607061/how-to-create-new-events-share-calendar-with-pytho.html

Comment: Do you see the shared calendars in Outlook?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Yes, if I open Outlook normally I can see the group calendars.

Comment: Is it a public folder? See [Create a Public Folder calendar in Exchange Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/collaboration-exo/public-folders/public-folders-calendar) for more information.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev You have to be added, it's not a public folder (unless I understand what you mean by public)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders (for example, their shared Calendar folder). So, you need to make sure the user as delegated access to you.

If the calendar is visible in Outlook's navigation pane you can access it using the [NavigationGroups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.navigationgroups) object. You can traverse the group and folder hierarchy of a module in the Navigation Pane by using the `NavigationGroups` and `NavigationFolders` collections. The `NavigationGroups` collection of the `NavigationModule` object contains each navigation group displayed in a navigation module, while the `NavigationFolders` collection of the `NavigationGroup` object contains each navigation folder displayed in a navigation group. By using these collections in combination, you can enumerate each navigation folder for a navigation module displayed in the Navigation Pane. Here is the sample VBA code where you can get the idea of the required OOM properties method to get the required calendar:

```
Dim WithEvents objPane As NavigationPane 
 
Private Sub EnumerateActiveCalendarFolders() 
 Dim objModule As CalendarModule 
 Dim objGroup As NavigationGroup 
 Dim objFolder As NavigationFolder 
 Dim intCounter As Integer 
 
 On Error GoTo ErrRoutine 
 
 ' Get the NavigationPane object for the 
 ' currently displayed Explorer object. 
 Set objPane = Application.ActiveExplorer.NavigationPane 
 
 ' Get the CalendarModule object, if one exists, 
 ' for the current Navigation Pane. 
 Set objModule = objPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(olModuleCalendar) 
 
 ' Iterate through each NavigationGroup contained 
 ' by the CalendarModule. 
 For Each objGroup In objModule.NavigationGroups 
 ' Iterate through each NavigationFolder contained 
 ' by the NavigationGroup. 
 For Each objFolder In objGroup.NavigationFolders 
 ' Check if the folder is selected. 
 If objFolder.IsSelected Then 
 intCounter = intCounter + 1 
 End If 
 Next 
 Next 
 
 ' Display the results. 
 MsgBox "There are " & intCounter & " selected calendars in the Calendar module." 
 
EndRoutine: 
 On Error GoTo 0 
 Set objFolder = Nothing 
 Set objGroup = Nothing 
 Set objModule = Nothing 
 Set objPane = Nothing 
 intCounter = 0 
 Exit Sub 
 
ErrRoutine: 
 MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, _ 
 vbOKOnly Or vbCritical, _ 
 "EnumerateActiveCalendarFolders" 
End Sub
```

The Outlook object model is common for all kind of programming languages, so it will not take a lot of efforts to recognize the sequence of properties and methods required to get the job done.

Comment: Thank you for the new lead, working through this now to see if it's what I'm looking for.

Comment: objPane = application.ActiveExplorer() simply returns none, meaning it doesn't have the attribute NavigationPane

Comment: You can use this way only if the explorer window is created. The [Explorers.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorers.add) method creates a new instance of the explorer window.

Comment: Ah thank you, I'm completely unfamiliar with how COM works and had the wrong idea from the beginning. I'm able to access my desired calendar now

Comment: [@Fen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1205930/fen) Can you post your working Python solution as an answer for others?

Comment: @wrkyle The Outlook object model is common for all programming languages. What exactly is unclear to you?

Answer (score 0):

Had to figure this out in python today so here it is:

```
import win32com.client

# Get Outlook Navigation Pane
outlook_navpane = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application').ActiveExplorer().NavigationPane

# Get the Outlook Calendar Module
outlook_navmod = outlook_navpane.Modules.getNavigationModule(1)

# Iterate through NavigationGroups and NavigationFolders
for group in outlook_navmod.NavigationGroups:
    # group.Name is My Calendars, All Group Calendars, etc.
    for folder in group.NavigationFolders:
        # folders are calendars
        calendar = folder.Folder
```