# How to access the derived objects from NavigationModule object (Outlook) using python?

Tags: python-3.x, outlook, com, pywin32, win32com

I am trying to make a python 3 script that reads the calendar events of the user (from a subfolder of the 'All Group Calendars' folder), filters them, then outputs the filtered ics file. I had an implementation based on GetSharedDefaultFolder, but that required the user being delegated, so I had to find a different solution. I stumbled upon the NavigationPane COM object and I have based a lot of my code [on this VBA code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70778543/get-outlook-group-calendars-using-pywin32-win32com-client). I tried my best to translate the VBA to python, but I do not know VBA so it was a bit of a struggle.

Here is my problem function:

```
import win32com.client
from icalendar import Calendar, Event 
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import re

def enumerate_group_calendars():
    outlook_app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    obj_pane = None

    try:
        obj_pane = outlook_app.ActiveExplorer().NavigationPane

        calendar_module = obj_pane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(1) # olModuleCalendar -> 1 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olnavigationmoduletype
        # print(calendar_module.NavigationModuleType)
        calendar_module_group = win32com.client.CastTo(calendar_module, "CalendarModule")
        if not calendar_module:
            raise Exception("Calendar module not found.")

        int_counter = 0
        filtered_events = []
        for obj_group in calendar_module_group.NavigationGroups:
            if obj_group.Name == "All Group Calendars":
                for obj_folder in obj_group.NavigationFolders:
                    if obj_folder.IsSelected:
                        int_counter += 1
                        process_subfolder_events(obj_folder, filtered_events)

    print(f"There are {int_counter} selected calendars in the Calendar module")
        print("Filtered Events:")
        for event in filtered_events:
            print(event)
        current_date = datetime.now().strftime("&Y-%m-%d")
        desktop_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop')
        ics_filename = os.path.join(desktop_path, f'filtered_events_{current_date}.ics')
        create_ics_file(filtered_events, ics_filename)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {str(e)}")
    finally:
        cleanup(obj_pane)
```

I have been reading the documentation of [NavigationModule object (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.navigationmodule) which says to "cast the NavigationModule object reference as one of the objects listed in the previous paragraph to access the NavigationGroups property for that object, such as a CalendarModule object." The same is reflected in the documentation of the [CalendarModule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.calendarmodule).

I tried to do the casting that the docs mention with `calendar_module_group = win32com.client.CastTo(calendar_module, "CalendarModule")`, but it produces the following error `Error: The interface name 'CalendarModule' does not appear in the same library as object '<win32com.gen_py.None.NavigationModule>'`.

I have also tried to access CalendarModule as if it was a method by replacing `for obj_group in calendar_module_group.NavigationGroups:` with `for obj_group in calendar_module_group.NavigationGroups.CalendarModule:`, but that produces this error `Error: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library._NavigationModule instance at 0x2108575392960>' object has no attribute 'NavigationGroups'`.

I have also tried to access CalendarModule as if it was a method by replacing `for obj_group in calendar_module_group.NavigationGroups:` with `for obj_group in calendar_module_group.CalendarModule.NavigationGroups:`, but that produces this error `Error: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library._NavigationModule instance at 0x2518609507520>' object has no attribute 'CalendarModule'`.

Comment: Solution for casting is to use `win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")` instead of `win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")`. This forces makePy to generate the _Calendar.py module and force early binding of the object. Additionally, `calendar_module_group = win32com.client.CastTo(calendar_module, "CalendarModule")` needs to be `calendar_module_group = win32com.client.CastTo(calendar_module, "_CalendarModule")`.